# Routing Error - No route matches [GET] "/auth/twitter" Omniauth-twitter with devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, omniauth

I'm trying to install omniauth-twitter and encountering some issues, mainly with the one outlined above. Initially I didn't have this issue but now I do so I'm scratching my head as to why this has cropped up.
I've placed the consumer key and secret key in the secrets.yml file and also in my omniauth.rb file as copied below. I've read an awful lot of conflicting information as to whether this file is required and all this information goes into the devise.rb file. I haven't altered or placed any reference to omniauth in my devise.rb file. I have also ensured the appropriate url callback link (http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback) has been placed in the twitter developers site.

Here's my code -

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  get "/auth/:provider/callback" => "social_logins#create"

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }  



  resources :users
  resources :events do

    resources :bookings
  end
  # get 'welcome/index'


  authenticated :user do
    root 'events#index', as: "authenticated_root"
  end


    root 'welcome#index'


end
```

social_logins.controller.rb

```
class SocialLoginsController < ApplicationController
  def create


    @details = request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml

    @provider = @details["provider"]
    @provider_id = @details["uid"]

    @user = User.where(provider: @provider, provider_id: @provider_id).first

    if @user.present?
        #sign them in
    else
        # make a new user
        @user = User.new
        @user.provider = @provider
        @user.provider_id = @provider_id

        # because of has_secure_password - will this work?
        @user.password = "AAAAAA!!"
        @user.password_confirmation = "AAAAAA!!"

        # let's save the key and secret
        @user.key = @details["credentials"]["token"]
        @user.secret = @details["credentials"]["secret"]

        # lets fill in their details
        @user.name = @details["info"]["name"]
        @user.email = @details["info"]["email"] || "aaaaa@email.com"

        @user.save!
    end


        session[:uid] = @user.id 
        flash[:success] = "You've logged in"
        redirect_to root_path
    end

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<header>
 <nav>
            <div class="links">
                <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %>
                <%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path %>
                <%= link_to 'Go to Events', events_path %>
                <%= link_to "Log in with Twitter", "/auth/twitter" %>
            </div>

 </nav>         


</header>
```

omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :twitter, Rails.application.secrets.twitter_api_key, Rails.application.secrets.twitter_api_secret
end
```

Comment: please provide output for `rake routes |grep auth`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your user model?

```
devise omniauth_providers: [:twitter]
```